# I want to leave the default format of the InputMask dd/mm/yy = 20/12/2020 from primeng, when inserting the date in the form

Tags: angular, primeng

I already tried by dateFormat = "dd/mm/yy", but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="ui-g-4">
    <label for="data_orcamento">Data do orçamento <span class="m-red">*</span></label>
    <p-inputMask
        #data_orcamento="ngModel"
        [(ngModel)]="budget.data_orcamento"
        [ngClass]="{ 'ng-dirty ng-invalid': data_orcamento.invalid && data_orcamento.dirty }"
        mask="99/99/9999"
        dateFormat="dd/mm/yy"
        placeholder="00/00/0000"
        slotChar="__/__/____"
        id="data_orcamento"
        name="data_orcamento"
        required
    ></p-inputMask>
</div>
```

Comment: I can work and I think you don't need dateFormat. I looked up the [document](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/inputmask) I can't find dateFormat. I think you can remove dateForamt.

Comment: Yes, this dateFormat = "dd/mm/yy" was just to inform you that I already tried to format it that way and it wasn't. Only that the date entry in the form is dd/mm/yyyy. But thanks for the comment. ~,^